# HTTP Request From Webflow to Twilio Body Format - Webflow Logic Integration

Tags: httprequest, sms, webflow

I'm trying to send an HTTP request from Webflow to Twilio so that when a user submits a form on Webflow, a text message is sent to the phone number provided. I'm using their new Logic feature to achieve this. I have my Twilio credentials set up, but I'm not sure how to configure the body of the request to include the "To" phone number. I keep getting an error. I can't include images here but here is what my request body looks like, has to be JSON format.

{
"Body": "Hey name username"! Thanks for subscribing!",

"From":"+18647400789",

"To": "+1phoneNumberProvided"

}

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to set the phone number ID from webflow into the "TO" section on the request as a dynamic field. Not 100% sure to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like Twilio only accepts url-encoded format for the request body which is where you would put the To, From and Body fields. At the moment, Webflow Logic only allows JSON body so Twilio isn't compatible. I believe other messaging services like Bandwidth and MessageBird allow JSON body so those might work. However, these require business emails to sign up for so it's still not always the quickest solution :/